# Checking if more inputs are present EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have 24 columns and 30 rows in my worksheet. How can I check if some inputs are in there more than once and how to make them stand out?

Comment: [Find duplicate values fast by applying conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/find-duplicate-values-fast-by-applying-conditional-formatting-HA102809491.aspx)

Comment: And how to apply this for formulas? I have all cells with formulas that output some data. I mean like I have alot of them that are double or triple but how to show them all in different colors so I can easier distinct which one is which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to simply locate duplicated cells with changing their formats, then run this short macro:

```
Sub DuplicateFinder()
    Dim r As Range, Mesage As String
    Dim rBig As Range
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set rBig = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Mesage = ""
    For Each r In rBig
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rBig, r) > 1 Then
                Mesage = Mesage & vbCrLf & r.Address(0, 0)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Mesage = "" Then
        MsgBox "no duplicates"
    Else
        MsgBox Mesage
    End If
End Sub
```